# Slick result not found

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am new to Slick, and am struggling with some problems its causing me.

In my database I have saved a user with my email address. However, when I execute this method (implemented in DAO):

```
def getByEmail(email: String): Future[Option[User]] = {

    println(s":${email}:")
    println(db.run(users.filter(_.email === email).result.headOption).value)

    db.run(users.filter(_.email === email).result.headOption)
}
```

the printed result is None (I can verify that the email exists).

My application.conf is setup as below:

```
slick.dbs.default.profile = "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/databasename"
```

The entire DAO is implemented as:

```
package dao

import javax.inject.{Inject, Singleton}

import models.User
import play.api.db.slick.{DatabaseConfigProvider, HasDatabaseConfigProvider}
import slick.jdbc.{JdbcProfile, PostgresProfile}
import slick.lifted.ProvenShape

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

/**
  * Created by Marin on 08/09/2017.
  */
@Singleton
class UserDAO @Inject()(val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[PostgresProfile] {

    import profile.api._

    private class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {

        def id: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

        def email: Rep[String] = column[String]("email", O.Unique)

        def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name")

        def surname: Rep[String] = column[String]("surname")

        override def * : ProvenShape[User] = (id.?, email, name.?, surname.?) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
    }

    private val users = TableQuery[UserTable]

    def add(user: User): Future[User] = {

        val query = users returning users.map(_.id) into ((user, id) => user.copy(id = Some(id)))

        db.run(query += user)
    }

    def get(id: Long): Future[Option[User]] = {

        db.run(users.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption)
    }

    def getByEmail(email: String): Future[Option[User]] = {

        println(s":${email}:")
        println(db.run(users.filter(_.email === email).result.headOption).value)

        db.run(users.filter(_.email === email).result.headOption)
    }

    def listAll: Future[Seq[User]] = {

        db.run(users.result)
    }
}
```

I don't understand why the result keeps being None... I've come to this problem as I noticed that some Future's from my Play controller never completed...

Answer (score 1):

The result of the call to `db.run(...)` is a `Future`. According to [the documentation of `Future#value`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/concurrent/Future.html#value:Option[scala.util.Try[T]]):

> If the future was not completed the returned value will be `None`.

The way you're accessing the result is invoking `.value` immediately as soon as the call to `db.run` returns. This doesn't give Slick enough time to open the connection, execute the statement, and return the results. Therefore, you're getting `None`.

This is also evident by your comment about the controller's `Future` never completing. If this is the case then the call to `.value` will always return `None`.

Comment: Ok. But, that doesn't explain why the other future (the line under), without '.value', never completes

Comment: hm... add doesnt seem to work anymore... which is strange as it worked a few days ago

Comment: There can be many reasons for this. You may want to double-check that you're able to run `psql -h localhost -d databasename -U appUser` and execute a SQL query to retrieve the values.

Comment: I didn't specify any username or password for the database - in order to keep it simple... I am able to login to the desired database via psql and execute a query

Comment: I would assume that Slick needs at least a username. I also remember now that using `-h localhost` may not be enough to force a network connection (as opposed to a "trust" Unix socket connection). I'm sorry I can't help any further.